# Unable to update all rows using before_create

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I require a before_update callback that simply increases the values in a column by two that are greater than the value of the new row being created. However I am getting confused between referencing the column attributes in the existing table and the column attributes of the row I am inserting.

I am using the following reference:
http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/update_all

```
class Region < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_create :update_tree

  def update_tree
    Region.where('rgt >= ?', self.rgt).update_all(rgt: rgt+2) 
  end 
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to increment the rgt of each record that is greater than or equal to the `self.rgt` by 2, you may use:

```
  def update_tree
    Region.where('rgt >= ?', self.rgt).update_all("rgt = rgt + 2") 
  end
```

This will generate a query:

```
UPDATE "regions" SET rgt = rgt + 2 WHERE (rgt >= X)
```

(X is the value of the `self.rgt`)

Comment: Thank you however this results in an error "wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)". Can I also clarify that self.rgt is the rgt value of the new record before it is written.

Comment: I've updated the answer. I'm supposing that you need to increment each region rgt by 2, is that what you are trying to do?